# Spring Boot Reactive MongoDB API with GraphQL - "Java class is not a List or generic type information was lost"

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, graphql

I was browsing through a lot of articles and blogs to find the proper way to get the following running. I already achived the following:

- Spring Boot Application - works
- Imperative Spring Data MongoDB Connection to my Mongo Atlas Cluster - works
- Spring GraphQL Starter implementation (Resolvers, etc.) - works

Now I want to implement my last requirement. To have GraphQL subscriptions working I need to integrate the Spring Data MongoDB Reactive dependency and create a new GraphQL Resolver for Subscriptions. Here is the code that I added to the already working app (hopefully the code fragments give enough info to help me out).

### Gradle.kt

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive")
```

### MyApp.kt

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackages = ["com.myapp"])
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = ["com.myapp"])
class MyApp

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyApp>(*args)
}
```

### SubscriptionResolver.kt

```
@Component
class SubscriptionResolver(
    private val characterReactiveRepository: CharacterReactiveRepository
) : GraphQLSubscriptionResolver {

    fun allCharacters(): Flux<Character> {
        return characterReactiveRepository.findAll()
    }
}
```

### CharacterReactiveRepository.kt

```
interface CharacterReactiveRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<Character, String>
```

### character.graphqls

```
type Subscription {
   allCharacters: [Character]!
}
```

### Error

```
SchemaClassScannerError: Unable to match type definition (NonNullType{type=ListType{type=TypeName{name='Character'}}}) with java type (reactor.core.publisher.Flux<com.backend.domain.Character>): Java class is not a List or generic type information was lost: reactor.core.publisher.Flux<com.backend.domain.Character>
```

### Detailed Exception

https://pastebin.com/sEWmDaTE

### Edit 1

```
@Component
class SubscriptionResolver(
    private val characterReactiveRepository: CharacterReactiveRepository
) : GraphQLSubscriptionResolver {

    fun allCharacters(): Publisher<Character> {
        return characterReactiveRepository.findAll()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the sample, you should return:

```kotlin
@Component
class SubscriptionResolver(
    private val characterReactiveRepository: CharacterReactiveRepository
) : GraphQLSubscriptionResolver {

    fun allCharacters(): Publisher<List<Character>> {
        return characterReactiveRepository.findAll()
    }
}
```

Example application you can find here https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/samples/tree/master/spring-boot-webflux

Comment: I added *Edit 1* with that but still the same error is appearing :(

Comment: Did you try with `Publisher<Character> or `Publisher<List<Character>>`? Try to use `Character` instead of `[Character]`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I defined the subscription's method's return value as `[Character]!` meaning an array. But since `Flux<Character>` or `Publisher<Character>` is not an array but a single type in that context the resolving failed all the time.

Changing the schema to the following helped:

```
type Subscription {
   allCharacters: Character
}
```

Comment: Did it help? I just get `Expected source object to be an instance of 'com.example.jobscraperspringserver.types.Page' but instead got 'reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust'`.. I understand that it's been 2 years, just a cry for help here :)

Comment: Sorry I can't remember if anything fixed this. Usually I mark working answers